# Make CRUD request with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax, request, function-calls

I want to make ajax calls with nodeJS to an endpoint. I have done many "get" requests by doing

```
http.get('url', (res) => ....)
```

Now , I want to make "post, put and delete" request

For example, I would to like to do

```
http.post('url', 'body', (res) => ...)
http.put....
http.delete ...
```

When I did that http.post request, I obtain "TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function".
And this is my complete request

```
http.post(environment.url , req.body, (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
        return res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(data))
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    res.status(404).send(err)
});
```

It is possible ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason NodeJS don't seem to implement the other HTTP methods as their own methods in the http module. You'll have to use http.request and set the request method in the option.

In its most simple form, you should be able to write

```
var req = http.request({method: 'POST', path: url}, (res) => ...);
req.write(body);
req.end();
```

Source:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: Ok @ShamPooSham, but what can I do to send the req.body correctly in the option to avoid endPoint problems, because my endpoint is waiting for the req.body to save the data? Many thanks